# Problem with high Maximum tombstones per slice?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm seeing the stats below for one of my tables running `nodetool cfstats`

```
Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 23571
```

Per the Datastax doc:

> Maximum number of tombstones scanned by single key queries during the
>   last five minutes

All my other tables have low numbers like 1 or 2. Should I be worried? Should I try to lower the tombstone creation?

Answer (score 1):

Tombstones can impact on read performance if they are residing in frequently used tables. you should re-work on data modelling part. Also. you can lower the value of gc_grace_seconds so that tombstones clear fast instead of waiting default value 10 days.

Comment: Be very careful when lowering gc_grace_seconds. You should ensure that you complete a full repair within the gc_grace_seconds window, or you could see "zombie" data - records that were deleted - reappearing.